# How to set the nested property name in a association in EXTJS 5?

Tags: extjs, extjs5

My code for loading a nested data structure to a model.

[Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1ah9)

Data returned by the request

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'name',
    products: [
        { id:2, name: 'name2'}
    ]       
}
```

It works all fine until i change the nested data property to some other name. For example allproducts

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'name',
    allproducts: [
        { id:2, name: 'name2'}
    ]       
}
```

After this change it wont apparently load the nested data anymore. I'm looking for a way to set this property name for the reference. I've tried to edit the reference config like this, but without any luck

```
reference:{type:'ProductFamily' ,association: 'allproducts'}
```

Is there any other options for this ?

Answer (score 1):

I made three changes to the fiddle:

```
Ext.define('ap.model.Allproduct', {

var prs = newModel.allproducts();

allproducts: [
```

and it worked. But this is only a hack. The true solution is the following:

ExtJS will [search for a matching model name in the schema namespace, using the default namer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.Schema-cfg-namespace). You can create a [custom namer](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.schema.Namer) to get allproducts match to the Product model.

Comment: Thank for your response. Changing the model name is not a solution for me. The api can return very strange property names sometime. Also this situation will happen only occasionally. Which part of the namer should I override ? I'm looking at the manyToOne fn.